# Wait response for http.get()

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, promise

I'm trying to make a login function in using angular and ionic 2. This function will  verify if the user are cadastred at the database through a php server and return an user id.But http.get() works in asynchronous form, so i can't compare if the user exist's on database because the return of function is undefined. I tryed two ways, using observable and promises:

> With observable, function that calls the service:

```
login() 
  {
    this.usuario = this.loginservice.get_usuario(this.loginusuario).subscribe(response =>this.usuario = response);
    console.log(this.usuario);
  }
```

> Service code:

```
public get_usuario(usuario):Observable<any>
  {
      return this.http.get(this.urlusuario +"/"+ usuario.usuario +"/"+ 
   usuario.senha); 
  }
```

That way, the first time I click the button that triggers the login () function, I get the undefined value in response. The second time I click, it returns the value of the previous request.

> Using promise, function that calls the service:

```
login() 
  {
    this.usuario = this.loginservice.get_usuario(this.loginusuario);
    console.log(this.usuario);
  }
```

> service code:

```
public get_usuario(usuario):Promise<any>
  {
    var resultado;
      return this.http.get(this.urlusuario +"/"+ usuario.usuario +"/"+ usuario.senha).toPromise().then(function(data){
         return  data; 
      });
  }
```

Using promise I get the id return on the first execution of the login function, however I could not find any way to access the __zone_symbol__value which is where the object is stored according to the `console.log()`
[console response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLBK7.png)

I want to know if there is a way to wait for the http.get () response to continue program execution (in case of using observable) or how do I access the object that is returned from the promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `async` in the the function and `await` in the call promise

```
async login() 
  {
    await this.usuario = this.loginservice.get_usuario(this.loginusuario);
    console.log(this.usuario);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code where you call the service, you need to subscribe to your observable, and do whatever you want to happen after the call inside the subscription.

You also dont set `this.usuario = this.loginservice.get_usuario...` here. You're setting this.usario to equal the `Observable`, not the response of the `Observable`.

```
login() 
{
  this.loginservice.get_usuario(this.loginusuario).subscribe(response => {
    this.usuario = response;
    console.log(this.usuario);
  });
}
```

> That way, the first time I click the button that triggers the login () function, I get the undefined value in response. The second time I click, it returns the value of the previous request.

This happens because you're doing `console.log` without waiting for the subscription to finish. The second time you click, it returns the value of the previous request, because for the same reason, it's not waiting for the subscription to complete because `console.log` is not in the subscription, but by the time you click it a second time, the first request did finish. Therefore, `this.loginusuario` was set AFTER the first `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

$http.get functions returns Promise, because .get() method sends async ajax request. To write response to your variable you need to do this:

```
login () {
    var self = this;
    this.http.get('/url/').then(response => {
        self.usuario = response;
        // It will write response from server to your variable when the 
        // request will be done
    }).catch(error => /*Your error handler*/);
}
```